# JavaScriptSerializer Deserialize c#?

Tags: c#

> Error: The type arguments for method `'System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>(string)'` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
string url = null;
public int GetLinkedIn()
{
    var jsonString = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=" + url + "&format=json");

    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dictionary dynamic="" string="">>(jsonString);
    var count = Convert.ToInt32(json["count"]);

    return count;
}
```

Comment: What is this: `Deserialize<dictionary dynamic="" string="">`? What type do you expect it to be after deserialization?

Comment: `jsonString` contains JSON not Javascript.  Take a look at Newtonsft Json.Net

Comment: I don't think `Deserialize<dictionary dynamic="" string="">>` is even a valid syntax?

Comment: Also keep in mind that you need to give a `json` string, not a whole `Javascript` string.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Despite the name, [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer) is for (de)serializing JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScriptSerializer class to resolve the Json response

```
int GetLinkedIn(string url)
{
   url = "http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=" + url + "&format=json";
   var jsonString = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
   return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<LinkdInJson>(jsonString).count;
}
```

And you need to create a class to represent the entity of the Json response

```
public class LinkdInJson
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string fCnt { get; set; }
    public string fCntPlusOne { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The type argument to the `Deserialize` method is wrong, the correct form is

```
var dic = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: It looks to me it is a compile error that the type argument `<dictionary dynamic="" string="">` can not be recognized. I correct it with <dictionary<string, dynamic>> and it's working. However, I could not reproduce the error reported by the OP.

Comment: Sure, but can you explain that in your answer? That particular bit of syntax looks like a copy-paste error anyway, some autoformatting done by Visual Studio's XML editor.

Comment: OK, I improve my answer.